# Error: could not find function "pdwtest"

Tags: r

I applied the DW test to my pooled model in R and I get this error

> Error: could not find function "pdwtest"

What's wrong? I installed the package `lmtest`.

Comment: Have you loaded that package using `library()` function?

Comment: Yes, I loaded the package usigng library(lmtest) function.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the wrong library. The function `pdwtest()` is part of the [`plm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) package, and not of `lmtest`. Try this:

```
install.packages("plm")
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
pdwtest(inv ~ value + capital, data=Grunfeld, model="random")
#
#   Durbin-Watson test for serial correlation in panel models
#
#data:  inv ~ value + capital
#DW = 0.99636, p-value = 2.819e-13
#alternative hypothesis: serial correlation in idiosyncratic errors
```